# How many types of idols are there in temples?

Tags: belief, prayer

We can see a lot of type of idols in different temples. Can we categorized it  ? Also how many types of idols are there? Explanation with pictures will be perfect.

Comment: I can put up crores here, too broad :) and also off-topic

Comment: Off-topic , what ?

Comment: The question, we have millions of temples, billions of god, so you need the photograph and name of each?

Comment: it can be categorized like wood,stone,metal, etc....but explaining with pictures can be too long.

Comment: @jabahar - ha ha , i know that All things, there is some exact typical names for that.... Not wood , metal etc.... I think my question is perfect.